# Prime ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\cap \mathbb{Z}=(0)$. Why is $\mathfrak{p}\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$? Are all prime ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ of this form?

Comment: $uv \in \mathfrak{p}\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: You realize that $n=1$ is just Gauss' lemma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb Q[x_1, \dotsc, x_n] = \mathbb Z[x_1, \dotsc, x_n] \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$ is a localization of $\mathbb Z[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ at the multiplicative set $\mathbb Z - \{0\}$ and for localizations $R \to S^{-1}R$, it is well known that extension and contraction of prime ideals give you inverse bijections between the primes of $S^{-1}R$ and the primes of $R$, that do not meet $S$.

In your case, not meeting $S$ precisely means $\mathfrak p \cap \mathbb Z = (0)$, because $S = \mathbb Z - \{0\}$.

This answers both of your questions.